# range-v3: Concatenate a range and a single value without copying or moving?

Tags: c++, range-v3

How can a vector of objects and a single object be iterated over as-if they were the same range, without any copying or moving, in range-v3?

One possibility is to cast the single value to a `std::array<Object, 1>` and then concatenate this array with the vector of objects via `range::views::concat`:

**Improvised solution**

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/concat.hpp>

struct Object {

    int value = 0;

    Object()                                                      { std::cout << "Default " << value << "\n"; }
    Object(   int         value) : value(value)                   { std::cout << "Value " << value << "\n"; }
    Object(Object const& object) : value(object.value)            { std::cout << "Copy " << value << "\n"; }
    Object(Object     && object) : value(std::move(object.value)) { std::cout << "Move " << value << "\n"; }
};

int main() {
    
    // Prints "Value 0"
    std::array<Object, 1> objects {0};

    // Prints "Value 1"
    Object object {1};

    for(Object const& object : ranges::views::concat(objects, *reinterpret_cast<std::array<Object, 1>*>(&object))) {
        // Prints "0 1"
        std::cout << object.value << " ";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if the cast is safe. Assuming it is, developers are at risk of having to spend time to verify this. Hence this improvised solution is wanting.

**Question:** Is there an *elegant* solution for concatenating a view and a single value without copying or moving data?

---

I am aware of `range::views::single` but this causes `object` to be copied once and moved thrice when used in place of `reinterpret_cast` in the improvised solution.